# What is the meaning of compiler option "-l" in linking dynamic libraries?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

I feel confused when linking dynamic libraries. Though I used `-L$(DIR)  -l$(LIB)` to specify a library and its directory, `ldd` always told me this `.so` came from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

SO, I wonder if the only effect of `-l$(LIB)` is to help compiler check whether the function declaration is match?

Comment: Linking comes after compilation, so nothing in the above discussion appertains to C++ anymore in the strict sense. It's all about locating the compilation artifacts. The `-L` flag defines the *search path* where the libraries that you nominate with `-l` are searched for.

Comment: It just tells the linker to request _this library_, that's all. No matter where the _file of this library_ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SO, I wonder if the only effect of `-l$(LIB)` is to help compiler check whether the function declaration is match?

More or less yes, that's the purpose.

Even when linking against libraries which are dynamically loaded at runtime, the linker needs to resolve the functions defined in those.

In this case a stub library is created to resolve the function calls. This is the one provided using the `-l` option.